# how to use np.ix_ to execute 4 by 4 matrix operations ? i have to insert a small (4 by 4) matrix in to big matrix (10 by 10)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

how to do the matrix operations, so that it can produce results something like this:

[image: 4 by 4 matrix insertion into big matrix]

first matrix shown in the image is wrong output and the second matrix (below) is the expected output

I found that it can be done using np.ix_, but i'm not able to apply it.

thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's so puzzling about using `np.ix_`?

```
In [529]: res = np.zeros((10,10),int)
In [530]: res[np.ix_([1,7],[1,9])]=[[1,1],[1,-1]]
In [531]: res
Out[531]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

The same indexing can be used to select the nonzero values:

```
In [532]: res[np.ix_([1,7],[1,9])]
Out[532]: 
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 1, -1]])
```

OK, I'm inserting a (2,2) array because those are the obvious nonzero values.  For any other, just adjust the two lists/arrays provided to `ix_`.